# Можно ли в swiper сделать предпросмотр слайдов?

Tags: javascript, css, scss, swiper

вот как на картинке, без прозрачности можно, просто никак не могу найти в документации что-то похожее
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам такое надо https://swiperjs.com/demos#slides-per-view ?

Answer (score 0):

В Swiper нет этой функции из коробки, поэтому лучше использовать [splidejs](https://splidejs.com/)

там можно просто указать padding и всё будет хорошо.